# Set height of child elements equal to highest other element that are contained by Wrap Widget (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I need to have box alignment like on image below. I use Wrap Widget to wrap my items by two elements in a row. But as i see Wrap widget don't have stretch property for the crossAxisAlignment.

I use another method to build cardItem, to simplify my code, and re-use it for my four cards.
Maybe you know some other Widgets to help to do it.

[image]

Can someone help me with it. Please see my code below:

```
class Transfers extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transfers'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 10,
          runSpacing: 10,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildTransferItem(
              "assets/images/icon.png",
              "Some Text of this box",
              context,
            ),
            _buildTransferItem(
              "assets/images/icon.png",
              "Text",
              context,
            ),
            _buildTransferItem(
              "assets/images/icon.png",
              "Some Text of this box",
              context,
            ),
            _buildTransferItem(
              "assets/images/icon.png",
              "Some Text of this box",
              context,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTransferItem(
      String transferIcon, String transferTitle, BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5 - 20,
      height: ,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(140, 140, 140, 0.5),
            blurRadius: 6.0,
          )
        ],
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: screenAwareSize(20.0, context),
        horizontal: screenAwareSize(20.0, context),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            transferIcon,
            width: screenAwareSize(72.0, context),
            height: screenAwareSize(39.0, context),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: screenAwareSize(7.0, context)),
          Text(
            transferTitle,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: screenAwareSize(14, context),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't check it at my end though but try replacing Column with ListView in _buildTransferItem method might solve your problem.

Comment: That is not something you can achieve with `Wrap`. Depending on what  you want, you'll instead use a custom RenderBox.

Comment: @RémiRousselet can you write the answer for me?

Answer (score 8):

What you need is `InstrinsicHeight` widget.
Here is an example of how to solve your problem for any given number of cards in row. As you can see the `_generateRows(List<String> labels, int numPerRow)` function gets a collection of card labels and a number of cards in a row as input parameters and generates the layout:

```
  List<Widget> _generateRows(List<String> labels, int numPerRow) {
    Widget _buildTransferItem(String transferTitle, int numPerRow) {
      return Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / numPerRow - 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(140, 140, 140, 0.5),
                  blurRadius: 6.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 20,
              horizontal: 20,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.info,
                  size: 48,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 7),
                Text(
                  transferTitle,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    List<Widget> result = [];
    while (labels.length > 0) {
      List<String> tuple = labels.take(numPerRow).toList();
      for(int i = 0; i< tuple.length; i++){
        if (labels.length > 0) labels.removeAt(0);
      }
      Widget item = IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: tuple.map((s) => _buildTransferItem(s, numPerRow)).toList(),
        ),
      );
      result.add(item);
    }
    return result
        .expand((item) => [
              item,
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
            ])
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transfers'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: _generateRows(
            ["Some text of this box", "Text", "Some Text of this box", "Some Rather Long Text of this box", "Cool, yeah?", "Last"],
            3,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) widget takes into consideration intrinsic dimensions of the child which for most container widgets like Row, etc. will be definite numbers. But it comes with performance warranty of O(N^2) in complex cases as you may read in the API docs.
Here are screenshots of cases when number of cards per row are 2 and 3. Please note that this parameter is passed just once and is not hardcoded anywhere.

[image]

If there's an odd number of items it will center last item:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't want to set it in Row Widget, because in the future i can change it, and set three in row instead two as now. I need to do it dynamically

Comment: And on your example you don't center items vertically relative to page

Comment: Andrew, I shown you the approach. You will not be able to implement this with Wrap, since Wrap passes to its children an infinite height constraints. You will not be able to implement it with GridView either.
If you don't want to set it in Row  you may set it in something else, but essential here is that `IntrinsicHeight` widget does not pass constraints to its child, but behaves opposite, making one extra layout pass and taking the child intrinsic height as a layout parameter.
And centering items relative to the page, adding padding and margin, etc. - this you can do yourself I believe.

Comment: I understand you. But i need a solution for my problem exactly. I don't need some other answers that don't give me the possibility to set my cards in another location. If you know how it can be realized as i draw on the image, please give me the answer.

Comment: I've refactored code so it builds rows dynamically. You just pass the list of transfer titles and number of items per row, then it does everything else. Centering and spacing added as well.

Comment: @AndrewKovalchuk, have you checked latest updates? Was it helpful for you?

Comment: Yes, it is helpful for me. Thank you! It is not the best way, but it works!

Comment: So why didn't you accept the answer and awarded me the bounty which was there mate?

Comment: Because it is not good practice. I want to write clean code and make it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are applied width of Container using media Query. Same way you can apply for Height or you can write manual for example

height: 300.0,

And to match parent of Column you can write following code :

```
 Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, // match parent
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
children: <widget>[
  // your widget
]
```

Comment: I don’t want to set width, because I need to do it dynamically